# Have <em> tag produce non-italicized text in an italic context

Tags: html, css, typography

I have styled the `h4` tag to use an italic font styling `font-style: italic;`.  Works fine.

Within a header, I would like to sometimes emphasize words using the `em` tag.

When this happens, I'd like the emphasized words to be rendered in a non-italicized font to distinguish them from the surrounding text.

What are my options?

To be clear, when using `em` outside of `h4` headers (with non-italicized text), it should italicize the text.

Only when the surrounding text is italicized do I want `em` to behave differently.  I'd strongly prefer to do this using just HTML and global CSS properties.

The basic philosophy is this:  `em` should call attention to text by making it different from the text around it. I don't know how to do this in a way that's sensitive to the context of the surrounding text.

I'm wondering if there's a straightforward way to do so.

Answer (score 4):

Do like this

```css
h4 {
  font-style: italic
}

h4 em {
  font-style: normal /* initial */
}
```

```html
<h4>hey text italic by CSS</h4>
<h4><em>hey text normal because <code>em</code> is here</em></h4>
<em>hey text by default tag</em>
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS has no mechanism to set a rule based on the parent element's computed style.

You could use a descendant combinator and be explicit about everywhere you want it to be different:

```
h4 em { font-style: normal; }
```

Or you could use JavaScript and test each element's parent in turn…

```js
function italic() {
    var em = document.querySelectorAll("em");
    em.forEach(function (em) {
       var parent = window.getComputedStyle(em.parentNode).fontStyle
       if (parent === "italic") {
           em.style.fontStyle = "normal";
       }
    });
}

addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", italic);
```

```css
h4 { font-style: italic; }
```

```html
<h4>This is <em>em</em></h4>

<p>How <em>em can you get? You can <em>nest! So many <em>levels</em> deep</em>.</p>
```

Comment: Isn't JS an overkill here?

Comment: @dippas — Probably, but it does handle some use cases that are very hard to deal with in CSS, so it is an option worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option

```
h4 em{
  font-style:initial;
}
```

https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/jmrgPb

Comment: IE doesn't support Initial